# C++ как передать тип в функцию и использовать как псевдоним?

Tags: c++, ооп, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

Только начал изучать C++.Решил написать свой класс 'динамического массива'(в качестве обучения) как std::vector ,с 'умными' запросами на выделение памяти у os - при удалении элемента не очищать память сразу , а при запросе брать с запасом.

```
class ListEc 
{
private:
    int realSize;
public:
    int size;
    ListEc(?type?,int startSize,int countIterAppe,int reatePop)//конструктор
    {
    }

};
```

Но мне нужен тип как псевдоним для управления этим массивом, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 5):

Вам нужно почитать, что такое шаблоны в C++

```
template<class T> 
class ListEc 
{
private:
    int realSize;
    T* elements;
public:
    int size;
    ListEc(T el,int startSize,int countIterAppe,int reatePop)//конструктор
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: `T[] elements;` - не скомпилируется.

Comment: Да, точно, поправил